# how can I append whitespaces before a specified character in select query which results into a varchar2 string in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Current output:

```
Name     : Aman 
Surname :  Sahu
Organization         : XYZ Technology
```

Expectation:

```
Name           : Aman
Surname        : Sahu
Organization   : XYZ Technology
```

Info: To remove the spaces from the String  I have used `regexp_replace(output_string,'[[:space:]]+:',':')`
but this expression removes the spaces but ':' is still not aligned in the same line.

Can anyone has better solution ?

Comment: What does "aligned in the same line" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-step process to first append extra spaces and then strip the excess:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           output_string,
           '^(.*?):\s+',
           '\1               : ',
           1,
           0,
           'm'
         ),
         '^(.{15})\s+',
         '\1',
         1,
         0,
         'm'
       ) AS aligned_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (output_string) AS
SELECT 'Name     : Aman 
Surname :  Sahu
Organization         : XYZ Technology' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ALIGNED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | `Name : Aman` `Surname : Sahu` `Organization : XYZ Technology` |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d3475a736b0be1e63d769bb183937ca3)*